# Autowired not work in ContextLoaderListener

Tags: java, spring

I am pretty new to Spring, I don't know why the `Autowired` not work in my project.

Basically I want to print the memory usage every 5 seconds using `TimerTask`, and I want to create the `TimerTask` in my custom listener, which extends `ContextLoaderListener`. However, the `logMemoryTask` in `MyContextListener` is always null, can anybody tell me how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

**MyContextListener.java**

```
public class MyContextListener extends ContextLoaderListener {
    @Autowired
    LogMemoryTask logMemoryTask;
    public MyContextListener() {
        super();
        startLogMemory();
    }
    private void startLogMemory() {
        if (logMemoryTask != null) {
            logMemoryTask.run();
        } else {
            System.out.println("LogMemoryTask is null!"); //It always prints null
        }
    }
}
```

**LogMemoryTask.java**

```
public class LogMemoryTask extends TimerTask {
    @Autowired()
    @Qualifier("persistService")
    ILog<MemoryLog> persistService;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
        if (persistService != null) {
            persistService.addLog(
                    new MemoryLog(Long.toString(maxMemory), Long.toString(allocatedMemory), Long.toString(freeMemory)));
        } else {
            // logger.info("persistService is empty!");
            System.out.println("persistService is empty!");
        }
}
```

**My applicationContext definition**

```
<bean id="persistService" class="com.james.reg.service.PersistService">
    <property name="operationMapper" ref="operationMapper" />
    <property name="memoryLogMapper" ref="memoryLogMapper" />
</bean>
<bean id="logMemoryTask" class="com.james.reg.util.LogMemoryTask"></bean>
```

Comment: I believe your `ContextLoaderListener` is being instantiated by your servlet container, not by Spring. On a broader note, your use of that XML syntax suggests you're following a very outdated tutorial, and I suggest you look at the Spring Getting Started Guides with Spring Boot and Java-based configuration.

Comment: Listener is defined in `web.xml`, `<listener> <listener-class>com.james.reg.listener.MyContextListener</listener-class></listener>`, is it right? @chrylis

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally I decided to give up the `Autowired` for now, and found another way to achieve my goal.

First I overrode the `contextInitialized` to get the bean I want manually, and pass the instance to where I want:

```
public class MyContextListener extends ContextLoaderListener {
    private LogMemoryTask logMemoryTask;
    ILog<MemoryLog> persistService;
    private Timer t;
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent event) {
        super.contextInitialized(event);
        WebApplicationContext servletContext = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext());
        persistService = (ILog<MemoryLog>) servletContext.getBean("persistService"); // get the bean
        startLogMemory(persistService);
    }
    ...
}
```

And in `startLogMemory()`, I can manually create the instance of `LogMemoryTask`:

```
public class MyContextListener extends ContextLoaderListener {
    private LogMemoryTask logMemoryTask;
    ILog<MemoryLog> persistService;
    private Timer t;
    private void startLogMemory(ILog<MemoryLog> persistService) {
        t = new Timer();
        logMemoryTask = new LogMemoryTask(persistService);
        t.schedule(logMemoryTask, 0, 5000); // log the memory every 5 seconds
    }
    ...
}
```

Finally finish the ctor of `LogMemoryTask`, and override the `run` method:

```
public class LogMemoryTask extends TimerTask {
    private ILog<MemoryLog> persistService;
    public LogMemoryTask(ILog<MemoryLog> persistService) {
        super();
        this.persistService = persistService;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
         // do what you want to do periodically here
         ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, when the project starts to run, the listener will get the bean, and start the timer to log the memory usage. I hope I can get a more elegant way later...